# how to add jar files into the WEB-INF/classes directory?

Tags: java, xwork, webwork

I am trying to learn how to create a web application and I am using xwork and webwork. Freemarker for front end. my application(MyTestApp.war) works fine if I put the .class files into the classes/  directory as it is. in this manner - classe/com/prg/hworld/HelloWorld.class but the same file, when i create a jar and put it in classes/ directory, I get this error.

Action class [com.prg.hworld.HelloWorld] not found, skipping action [hello]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prg.hworld.HelloWorld
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1332)

I hav added the jar name in the manefest.mf but stil i am getting the same error.. pls help me her..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jar must go inside WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1):

Put jar files to WEB-INF/lib directory

[some more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29)